# Android WebView with JavascriptInterface - Memory Leak?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, webview

I am developing custom browser, which is able to open more tabs, as common browsers do. My Browser Activity consists of ViewPager. Tabs are implemented in Fragments - each WebView has its own fragment (tab) in ViewPager. Tabs are dynamically added/removed from ViewPager.

Analyzing memory dump I found out, that WebFragments removed from pager are not garbage collected and stay in memory. In Memory Analysis perspective, I use to list my WebFragments with incoming references and then I use option "Merge Shortest Paths to GC Roots" -> "exclude all phantom/weak/soft etc. references". This is what I see:
[image: screenshot]

"App" at the top is my Application context, at bottom you can see my leaked WebFragment and its javascript interface (JSInterface) above it.

I add my JSInterface in WebFragment the standard way:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), JSInterface.JSINTERFACE_NAME);
```

(JSInterface is private class in WebFragment)

**Does JS interface cause my WebFragment leak? How can I get rid of that? Thank you!**

Comment: possibly your `JSInterface` references a context?

Comment: No, JSInterface doesn't reference any objects, unless its WebFragment, which it needs to be able to cooperate with (see curtisLoew's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your javascript interface is still referenced by `WebKit` parts.

Call `removeJavaScriptInterface(JSInterface.JSINTERFACE_NAME);` to explicitly unreference it.

Comment: I implemented JSInterface as separate class, then I also managed to have WebFragments garbage collected by null-ing JSInterface's reference to it, but now JSInterfaces seem to be leaked also when I call removeJavaScriptInterface...I will research more, thank you. Another disadvantage is that removeJavaScriptInterface requires at least Honeycomb...

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `JSInterface` static.

Comment: why shouldn't this be in a comment?

Comment: @code-jaff I believe this is a potential answer to the question and therefore not a suitable comment.

Comment: Unfortunbately it didn't help. :-( To make it static I had to reference WebFragment in JSInterface class to be able to cooperate with its functions, webview etc...but the situation is the same.